# Cross-talk filter with known source

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

I currently work in an experimental rock mechanics lab, and when I conduct an experiment, I record the output signals such as effective torque, normal force and motor velocity. However, the latter quantity causes significant cross-talk over the recorded channels, and I want to filter this out. Let me give an example:
[image]
Here the upper plot is the strong signal (motor velocity), and the lower is an idle signal that is affected by the cross-talk (blue is raw signal, red is median filtered). The idle channel is only recording noise. We see three effects here. When the motor voltage changes:

1. the amplitude of the noise increases
2. the idle signal's median shifts
3. there is a spike that lasts approximately 0.1 seconds

If we zoom in on the first spike that occurs at around 115 seconds, we get the following plot. This does not seem to be your typical delta-function type of spike, but rather some kind of electronic "echo".
[image]

I have seen much work on blind source separation through independent component analysis (ICA), but that did not prove to be effective in my situation. However, since I know the shape of the signal that is causing the cross-talk, there may be better ways to include this information. My question is this: is there a filter or a combination of filters that can tackle the effects mentioned above?

As I am a geologist and not an electrician or mathematician, I don't have a proper background for this kind of material, so please bear with me. I write Python, MATLAB and C++ quite well, so suggested algorithms written in any of those languages is preferred (but not required).

Answer (score 0):

The crosstalk you encounter, results from a parasitic transmission line. Just think of your typical FM-receiver - where the wires equal the antennae. These effects include parasitic and inductive coupling, and form an oscillator (which is the reason, why you cannot see, the theoretically ideal delta spike)

I recognize two different approaches:

1. use a hardware filtering circuit
2. use a software-implemented filter

ad 1:
depending on the needed bandwith (maximum frequency/rate of change) on the idle channel, you can determine the corner frequency, as well as the required filter-order, for a given rate of suppression

ad 2:
you can implement several types of filters (IIF, FIR) which resemble these circuits.
**Additionally**, if you are measuring the aggressive signal anyways, you can use the measurement on the idle channel to determine system-parameters for a mathematical model of the crosstalk. With this model you'd be able, to exclude the interference by calculation